# Retrieve Information from Registry Key Using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, registrykey

I am using PowerShell to read information from the registry key.

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice\" |% {$_.ProgId}
```

It's basically to find what is the default browser on the machine.

However, I am keep running into this error. I am new to PowerShell, so not sure what is going on.

```
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\user1\Documents\Files\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice\' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Assoc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\user1...ttp\UserChoice\:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
```

Is there any other way to get a Data (**ProgId**)from the registry key?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In powershell version 5 you can use the following command to get the value of ProgId in that path in the registry.

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice -Name ProgId
```

The difference between the Get-ItemProperty and Get-ItemPropertyValue is that the latter only returns the value.

The path you were using was interpreted as a file location since the provider for the file system is the default. So when you want to use the registry you must use HKCU: for HKEY_CURRENT_USER and HKLM: for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

If you are not on v5 yet, you can use:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice).ProgId
```

Comment: `Get-ItemPropertyValue` only became available in PowerShell 5.0

Comment: You are right. Before that i would use. (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice).ProgId

Answer (score 3):

Your current command is referencing a file in the local filesystem. You need to use the provider for the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry hive (`HKCU:`):

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice\" |% {$_.ProgId}
```

Comment: How can I get the "Default" value? In this case, it's not set, but in another case I am working on has a 'Default' value. I replace "ProgId" with Default, but it didn't work.

Comment: `... | % { $_."(default)" }`.

Comment: I replaced it, but it does not returns anything.

Comment: @MoA Works for me: `Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" | % { $_."(default)" }` returns `Windows Aero`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the provider and the different notation, you can use one of the following notation:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice" -Name ProgId
```

OR

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice" -Name ProgId
```

using the full ROOT notation HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, you should specify the provider (Registry::)
using the short notation HKLM, you can avoid and should be HKLM:\

Note:
Those notations are called PSDrive in Powershell for the registry.
2 are defined by default:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry
```

Output:

> HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
>   HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

you can define other PSdrive

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry
```

> HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
>   HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>   HKU                                    Registry      HKEY_USERS